# Is there a name for the bright lights/fuzzy spots that are seen after head trauma?

Tags: neurology, head-trauma, concussion

I have had a number of concussions and the one thing I remember quite a few times is seeing bright spots or  white fuzzy spots in my vision briefly after. A similar thing occurs when I have particularly bad migraines, and my doctor calls it "aura." Is there a specific name for these visual distortions related to head trauma? If not for these specific visual distortions, do temporary visual distortions after head injury have a name? I am guessing the answer is no, because I can't even find these visual distortions mentioned. Everything I see talks about blurred and double vision, problems with near sightedness, or other issues, but nothing with blotchy lights.

Comment: Google migraine aura.

Comment: I guess, a way to rephrase my question is what is migraine aura after injury with no migraine called. After the head injuries, the pain is initially typically minimal. My head is kind of numb, but I still have these visual disturbances. So, I get the aura, without the migraine. (The migraine comes usally several hours to days later).

Comment: Many people experience migraine aura without headache. (I'm one of them.) Your question was borderline personal medical advice, which is strictly off topic here, but since you only asked to name the condition, I let it stand. But what you're asking now is definitely personal medical advice no one here can answer. If the doctors treating you don't know what migraine aura is, get a second opinion.